# Есть ли готовый компонент angular для плиточного отображения элементов?

Tags: css, typescript, angular

Искал готовый компонент для плиточного отображения/вида элементов для web приложения (как в проводнике). Не нашел компонента с встроенной группировкой/сортировкой, может кто знает такой?
[image: пример того что надо]

Comment: Иногда проще самому написать чем искать. Реализовать такую директиву очень просто.

Comment: Может быть, но не хотелось бы писать велосипед :)